# Magento : Can I limit the store hours?

Tags: magento

I am looking to find out if its possible to limit my Magento store in terms of hour. Example: I am planning on working with a restaurant using Magento as an online ordering mechanisms. But instead of people being able to order 24/7 I want them to order between 11 AM and 10 PM Local Time. I simply want to remove the option to place orders and checkout during those times but still allow the items/Menu to be visible. Does anyone have any experience with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would leverage Magento's config system and create a "can_order" value. Keep it updated as B00MER suggested via cron. Hook in to 'catalog_product_is_salable_after' change the value of 'salable' accordingly. You can also reuse the config value to place a banner globally to inform viewers of the store hours.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the maintance.flag file for closing down the store completely, and simply use the same methodology, but simply add an additional check if the customer is attempting to hit cart page and redirect them to a notice about business hours.

for example this in your index.php, and then have a cron job remove and add the 'closed.flag' file when the store is closed for online ordering. (this example not tested but should give you the general idea)

```
if(file_exists('closed.flag') && $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] == "checkout") 
{
   include_once dirname(__FILE__) . 'closed.php'; exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @B00mer I'll be sure to give that a try. Do you think that I'd be able to implement that via the backend or I would need to go into the file editor every single day to make the change?

Comment: http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html a simple script that would `touch closed.flag` and `rm closed.flag` would avoid any manual intervention.